# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "omniauth"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Im trying to implement stripe omniauth in my application but also using google omniauth too. Both gems relies on gem omniauth but in different versions, anyone knows how to solve it?

The error I get when try to bundle:

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "omniauth":
  In Gemfile:
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (>= 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      omniauth (~> 2.0)

    omniauth-stripe-connect was resolved to 2.9.0, which depends on
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
```

Comment: If it is possible to downgrade omniauth-google-oauth2 to `0.8.2` it can live with omniauth-stripe-connect 2.10.1 in the same Gemfile


I just tried and got this working:


Using omniauth 1.9.1
Using omniauth-oauth2 1.7.1
Using omniauth-google-oauth2 0.8.2
Using omniauth-stripe-connect 2.10.1

Comment: @sel_space Thank you, it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to downgrade omniauth-google-oauth2 to 0.8.2 it can live with omniauth-stripe-connect 2.10.1 in the same Gemfile I just tried and got this working:

```
Using omniauth 1.9.1
Using omniauth-oauth2 1.7.1 
Using omniauth-google-oauth2 0.8.2 
Using omniauth-stripe-connect 2.10.1
```